# Data Recovery from Formatted external hard drive

Tags: data-recovery

I have an external hard disk. I plugged it into my friend's laptop. It doesn't show up in "My Computer" or Command Prompt. So as usual I plugged out and in again. Then in "My computer" it says the hard disk need to be formatted before you can use it. And I can't access the drive which prompts "Access Denied". The external hard drive had been formatted currently. And I want to recover the files in that hard disk. I want to know which software is the best in recovering data from formatted hard drive. Please give me an exact direct download link if you don't mind. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I'm sorry, but asking for recommendations on products is not considered a useful question. Please try some tools yourself – I'm sure there's plenty to be found, like TestDisk, etc – and let us know if you have any concrete issues with that.

Comment: @slhck Thanks for your advice. I am new here, that's why. But i do want to recover my data back. I have tried using some, but they are taking ages just to analyze the hard disk.

Comment: @TitanZack that's normal.  Good recovery software takes a long time.  It's not uncommon for analysis to take hours to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did a full format, then you may as well consider them gone, but if it quick-formatted, then you cannot undelete but should be able to use a low-level data-recovery program.

Despite its name, [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) can scan a disk and save many filetypes. The developers of PhotoRec also created the more advanced [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which can attempt to do some additional recovery as well as perform some tests on the drive.

That said, the "recovered" files are not guaranteed to be correct. If they were fragmented, they can be corrupt, incomplete, or even completely incorrect. Further, the original directories, filenames, and timestamps will not be restored.

Answer (score 1):

Open up Disk Management when it is plugged in and booted up by right clicking on My Computer -> manage, and then select Disk Management from left menu.

click on the drive and right click and select change drive letter. This should help (If I have understood the issue correctly)

Comment: That would help if i hadn't formatted the external hard disk. I have formatted it. And I want the data back.

Comment: Try Google - many offer a free trial which will allow you to see what you can get back before paying so you can be confident with your choice.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't even have credit card, debit card, or any kind online payment. I am from Myanmar that's why.

Comment: Google 'free hard drive recovery' then?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best programs are [Recover My Files](http://recover-my-files-data-recovery-software.soft32.com/) or [Stellar Phoenix Win Data Recovery](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Back-Up-and-Recovery/Stellar-Phoenix-Windows-Data-Recovery.shtml/). Both of them are useful and strong programs for you.